# How do I get "The Witcher II" working with wine?

Tags: wine, games

Hi I'm tring to run the witcher II with wine on ubuntu 11.10...but after that appear the blue screen of wine it close it self and nothing appen...what could be?

- I'm using Wine 1.3.35.
- My vide card is an Nvidia Geforce 220M and the driver is 290.1

Comment: what version of wine are you using - N.B. winehq are reporting gold rating with 1.3.23 http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=23504

Comment: I'm using wine 1.3.35

Comment: what graphics card and driver are you using...?

Comment: it's a nvidia gforce 220M and the driver is the 290.1

Comment: its good that you are using nvidia since wine games work best with nvidia.  Is this a full screen issue?  can you run the game in a window via winecfg? I would file a bug report at winehq.org if you cant get it to work.

Comment: yes of course I do...just a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing trough PlayOnLinux? It's a program that loads specific wine versions/settings based on what you want to run. I've used it for other games and for me works best than "bare" wine...

Comment: yes I've trien with playonlinux and at the end of the installshield the message is this...and the game it's not installed: [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/687/bugwineplayonlinux.png/)

Comment: I can't really read the name of the program that crashed, I assumed you looked into it (and the fact that it looks like a 64bit executable)...